# LIKE wildcards in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am writing a piece of code where @Variant is provided. I wanted to store multiple values by capturing them in a variable (runtime) and pass them in the WHERE clause. Share the logic

```
DECLARE @Variant VARCHAR(50)
SET @Variant='''25'',''33'''
SELECT @Variant  ---- which is actually '25','33'
SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE '25' IN (@Variant)

DECLARE @Variant VARCHAR(50)
SET @Variant='''25'',''33'''
SELECT @Variant  ---- which is actually '25','33'
SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE '25' IN (SELECT @Variant)
```

Above queries do not work...

```
--DECLARE @Variant VARCHAR(50)
--SET @Variant='''25'',''33'''
--SELECT @Variant
SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE '25' IN ('25','33')
```

Above is a simpler query in SQL Server -which I tried if SQL accepts. My actual query is to pass wild cards in the LIKE statement in WHERE clause.

DECLARE @Variant VARCHAR(50)
    SET @Variant='''25%'' OR [Item_No] LIKE ''33%'''
    SELECT @Variant
    SELECT * from Table1 WHERE [Item_No] LIKE (@Variant) --I presume @variable will be replaced with its value during execution.

Anyways, simpler way - I have a Item_No in the Where clause to which i want to supply multiple wild cards. Is there a method similar to inline function, which should replace the text at the @variant and execute combining it.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `LIKE` or wildcards. Fix the tags please.

Comment: why have you tagged 'wildcard' and 'like'?

Comment: Looks like the title does not really match the question. Same goes for the tags.

Comment: oracle doesn't support select without from clause if that is the case.

Comment: Based on the syntax, this is SQL Server, and if so, a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x or any of the similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> DECLARE @Variant VARCHAR(50)
> SET @Variant='''25'',''33'''
> ```

At this point `@Variant` contains a single string.

> ```
> SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE '25' IN (@Variant)
> ```

Given the `25` does not equal `'25','33'` this is never going to match. (`IN` is looking for an exact match – equality – with at least one of the set of values supplied in the parentheses.)

SQL will not magically parse a string into a collection. You'll need to tell it to. Options to do this depend on the particular DBMS you are using. They include temporary tables and table valued variables.

Comment: Thanks Richard - your explanation "Given the 25 does not equal '25','33' this is never going to match"

Answer (score 0):

`SQL` `Like` condition will work in your scenerio.

```
DECLARE @Variant VARCHAR(50)
SET @Variant='''25'',''33'''

SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE @Variant like '%25%'
```

Here result is `TRUE`. Hope this will help.

Comment: And what if `@Variant = '25,33,255,256'` ?